# Implement Pagination in ASP.Net Gridview Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, footer

I have a gridview that is bound on page load and I've implemented insert using the footer row technique.

Now I tried the pagination in the same gridview.

I don't have errors but when changing page in the DDL of footer row I find all  values duplicates.

In first page the output in DDL is:

```
MSG
PAY
BUY
LIS
```

If changed the page the second output in page number two is:

```
MSG
PAY
BUY
LIS
MSG
PAY
BUY
LIS
```

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

I used this lines in RowDataBound:

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            DropDownList Area_DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Area_DDL");
            Area_DDL.DataTextField = "area_name";
            Area_DDL.DataValueField = "area";
            Area_DDL.DataSource = Area();
            Area_DDL.DataBind();
            Area_DDL.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("Area") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList Area_DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Area_DDL");
            Area_DDL.DataTextField = "area_name";
            Area_DDL.DataValueField = "area";
            Area_DDL.DataSource = Area();
            Area_DDL.DataBind();
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlpages"));
            Label lblPageCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPageCount");

            if (lblPageCount != null)
                lblPageCount.Text = GridView1.PageCount.ToString();

            for (int i = 1; i <= GridView1.PageCount; i++)
            {
                ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            ddl.SelectedIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

            if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
            {
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")).Visible = false;
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton2")).Visible = false;
            }

            if (GridView1.PageIndex + 1 == GridView1.PageCount)
            {
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton3")).Visible = false;
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton4")).Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this, I hope it help:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridViewBind();
}

protected void ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvrPager = GridView1.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList ddlPages = (DropDownList)gvrPager.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPages");

    GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex;
    GridViewBind();
}

protected void Paginate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intCurIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;        

    switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "First":
            GridView1.PageIndex = 0;                
            break;
        case "Prev":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex - 1;
            break;
        case "Next":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex + 1;
            break;
        case "Last":
            GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageCount - 1;
            break;
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlpages"));
        Label lblPageCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPageCount");

        if (lblPageCount != null)
        {
            lblPageCount.Text = GridView1.PageCount.ToString();

            for (int i = 1; i <= GridView1.PageCount; i++)
            {
                ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            ddl.SelectedIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

            if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
            {
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")).Visible = false;
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton2")).Visible = false;
            }

            if (GridView1.PageIndex + 1 == GridView1.PageCount)
            {
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton3")).Visible = false;
                ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton4")).Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```